# Get all asp net column values if it's a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can get all my values from a column full of text boxes using:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    string value = row.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

But how can I do it if the control in column 3 (`Cells[2]`) is a DropDownList?

I've got Boundfields:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Area" HeaderText="My Area" SortExpression="Area" ReadOnly="true">
    <ItemStyle  Wrap="False" />
    <HeaderStyle  Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

Is there a way to get the value directly?

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch values from UI instead going to the bindings source and fetch data from there? Can you better describe the use-case you are facing?

Comment: Not sure how I can pull data directly from the source for each row once it's bound?  edited my question, I'm using boundfields. Can I ID the column and then the row values?

Comment: It's a progress... you also defined a data source that holds the original data (reflected in your form controls). If you manipulate the data source instead of running over textual values reflected in UI, you will be able to solve your problem (regardless to the controls your are using)

Comment: Yeah I've just populated a `DataTable` using the bound `GridView` `DataSource`... can't see the wood for the trees.

Comment: you should share more parts of your code... seems like you need some help to better understand the code you are currently facing

Comment: Nah it's fine, once I remembered I can access the source it was a piece of cake with `List<string> strs = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>(columnHeader)).Distinct().ToList();` where `dt` is my `DataTable`;